# Lightning - static resource deployment - javascript code

Tags: static-resources, lightning-aura-components, cache

I am using the migration tool to deploy javascript files containing logic to display charts in a lightning component.

To test my code I need to set the chrome developer console to not cache files to see my changes. Is there another way as I would like to be able to test in different number of browser and devices.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you're using to reference your static resources?